# Netbeans 6.9 Vertical Line on Screen

Tags: netbeans

I cannot figure out how to remove this vertical line every time I start Netbeans 6.9 and open any file, it's just right there.

[image: Netbeans Vertical Line Screenshot]

Comment: What is the use of red margin ?

Answer (score 90):

*Weew!* I found it.

For those experiencing this same problem, I just want to share how I made it disappear. So this vertical line is actually called the Right Margin.

In **Mac**, it's under

`Preferences > Editor > Formatting`

In **Windows** and **Ubuntu** it's

`Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting`

and then a zero value for Right Margin. ^^

Comment: In Ubuntu its Tools->Options->Editor

Comment: In Windows it's also Tools->Options->Editor

Answer (score 56):

After using @Justinn Cribb's answer I wanted to write to add a few details to those who may have problems:

First you have top open your platform specific Editor Options menu:

- **Mac**: NetBeans->Preferences->Editor
- **Ubuntu**: Tools->Options->Editor
- **Windows**: Tools->Options->Editor

Then follow these steps:

1. Make sure you're in the Formatting Tab.
2. Change the Language to "All Languages"
3. Change the Right Margin to 0
4. Click Apply or Ok

[image: Steps]

Answer (score 4):

This can also be set as a project specific option. This is given priority over the NetBeans global option. I've found this useful when working with different coding standards and projects on the same computer.

On Windows, this can be found in:

**File** > **Project Properties** > **Formatting**, select '**Use project specific options**', and modify as required.

[image: NetBeans Project Properties (Formatting) dialog]

Answer (score 1):

On windows (NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 ):

Tools>>Options>>Editor>>Formatting

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *hide* the line, you can change its color:

Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > Highlighting > Category > Text Limit Line.

I changed it to transparent.

(Tested in Netbeans 11.2).