# How to hide vertical line in NetBeans editor window?

Tags: netbeans

How to hide vertical line in editor (or change it position)?

[image]

Comment: This is a clear duplicate of [Netbeans 6.9 Vertical Line on Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3221855/2985643). Please check existing questions before posting, especially for very basic issues like this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netbeans 6.9 Vertical Line on Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221855/netbeans-6-9-vertical-line-on-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Tools / Options / Editor / Right Margin use 0 as a value.